# Batch file txt transformation

Tags: batch-file

I have a convert request, need to transform a txt file to show up only the distincted folders in BATCH.

So here is an example file:

```
zpaq v7.15 journaling archiver, compiled Aug 17 2016
zpaq_m1.zpaq: 1 versions, 14 files, 125 fragments, 4.521800 MB

- 2017-03-31 21:22:24      9025719 D     c:/2/testdata/
- 2016-09-26 13:26:07         9149 A     c:/2/testdata/test.txt
- 2017-03-31 21:22:48      9014621 D     c:/2/testdata/Subfolder/
- 2017-03-31 21:22:59        11856 D     c:/2/testdata/Subfolder/History/
- 2017-03-31 21:22:24        11856 D     c:/2/testdata/Subfolder/History/2016-03-12/
- 2016-03-11 23:31:49         1976 A     c:/2/testdata/Subfolder/History/2016-03-12/00h31m49s  v1.9.m3p
- 2016-03-11 23:36:47         1976 A     c:/2/testdata/Subfolder/History/2016-03-12/00h36m47s  v1.9.m3p
- 2016-03-11 23:37:09         1976 A     c:/2/testdata/Subfolder/History/2016-03-12/00h37m09s  v1.9.m3p
- 2016-03-11 23:38:34         1976 A     c:/2/testdata/Subfolder/History/2016-03-12/00h38m34s  v1.9.m3p
- 2016-03-11 23:40:00         1976 A     c:/2/testdata/Subfolder/History/2016-03-12/00h40m00s  v1.9.m3p
- 2016-03-11 23:40:25         1976 A     c:/2/testdata/Subfolder/History/2016-03-12/00h40m25s  v1.9.m3p
- 2016-03-11 23:39:43      9001472 A     c:/2/testdata/Subfolder/test.exe
- 2017-03-28 10:45:03         1293 A     c:/2/testdata/Subfolder/test.ini
- 2016-09-26 14:04:43         1949 A     c:/2/testdata/todo.txt

9.025719 MB of 9.025719 MB (14 files) shown
  -> 9.017815 MB (129 refs to 125 of 125 frags) after dedupe
  -> 4.521800 MB compressed.
```

So here are the steps which I want to transform the file:

1. Remove the first three lines
2. Remove the last four lines
3. Cut the first 41 letters of each line
4. Replace Forward slash to Backslash
5. Remove everything after the last Backslash (so the filenames)
6. Distinct the file, so that each Folder is only be there once

So the final Result should be:

```
c:\2\testdata\
c:\2\testdata\Subfolder\
c:\2\testdata\Subfolder\History\
c:\2\testdata\Subfolder\History\2016-03-12\
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Here is my current status:

```
::delete first 2 lines 
for /f "skip=1 delims=*" %%a in (Listing.txt) do (
echo %%a >>Listing2.txt    
)

::delete last 3 lines
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=
for /f %%x in ('type Listing2.txt ^| find /c /v ""') do set /a lines=%%x-3
copy /y nul %tmp%\tmp.zzz > nul
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('type Listing2.txt ^| find /v ""') do (
  set /a count=count+1
  if !count! leq %lines% echo %%x>>%tmp%\tmp.zzz
)
move /y %tmp%\tmp.zzz Listing2.txt > nul

::Delete last cr flag at the end of the file
::@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "firstLineReady="
(
    for /F "eol=$ delims=" %%a in (Listing2.txt) DO (
        if defined firstLineReady (echo()
        set "firstLineReady=1"
        <nul set /p "=%%a"
    )
) > Listing_Final.txt
del Listing2.txt /f /q

::take everything after line 1 und each line after character41
for /f "skip=1 usebackq delims=" %%i in ("Listing_Final.txt") do call :ProcessLine "%%i"
:PROCESSLINE
set "Zeile=%~1"
::put everything after 41
(echo %Zeile:~41%)>>"Listing_Final_Folder_Files_temp.txt"


del Listing_Final.txt /f /q


::Remove double entries
::@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (Listing_Final_Folder_Files_temp.txt) DO SET $%%a=Y
(FOR  /F "delims=$=" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO ECHO %%a)>Listing_Final_Folder_Files_temp2.txt

::del Listing_Final_Folder_Files_temp.txt /f /q
```

Now I am trying to convert the slash to backslash but with this code it is not working:

```
::Replace / to \
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%f IN ("Listing_Final.txt") DO (
 set old=%%f
 echo !old!
 set new=!old:/=\!
 echo !new!>tesss.txt  
 echo.                 
)
```

The last step is to remove everything after the last \ but I did not find anything.

Comment: Great.. You've broken it down into tasks. So start researching how to complete task 1. When you've figured that out, move on to adding task 2, and repeat until you've got it done. This is not a code writing service, where you post a detailed list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code to meet them. We expect an effort on your part to find a solution on your own before posting here

Comment: I suggest you visit [ss64.com/nt](http://ss64.com/nt) and take a close look at the commands `set,find,for /f,sort and maybe if`

Comment: yes you are right, sorry its my first post. Here is my current status:

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you to use an *entirely different* method?

- Instead of remove the first three and last four lines, you may process just the lines that start with "-"; this allows to process any file with more or less lines.
- Instead of cut the first 41 *characters* of each line, you may process just the 6th space-delimited token of each line.
- Instead of remove everything after the last Backslash, you may get the drive and path of such a token. This also *automatically* converts any Forward slash to Backslash.
- Finally, you may use such a value as *subscript* to define array elements, so just elements with unique subscripts remains, instead of look for and delete duplicate elements.

.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Processing lines that have a dash in first column, get the sixth token
for /F "tokens=6" %%a in ('findstr "^-" Listing.txt') do (

   rem Get just the drive and path of sixth token
   rem at same time, convert Forward slash to Backslash
   rem and use it as the subscript of an array,
   rem so just unique elements are stored:

   set "folder[%%~DPa]=1"
)

rem Show the result
for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('set folder[') do echo %%a
```

Output:

```
c:\2\testdata\Subfolder\History\2016-03-12\
c:\2\testdata\Subfolder\History\
c:\2\testdata\Subfolder\
c:\2\testdata\
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Aacini, very good ideas. It tells me, that the variable "folder[" is noch definied. What do I need to do?

Comment: This is what I did: I copied your example data and pasted it into a file called `Listing.txt`; then, I copied the batch code into `test.bat` file placed in the same folder of the data file. Finally, I run it. I just did the same again in other computer and get the same result. I suggest you to do _exactly the same_...